# Call a method after 2 other asynchronous methods are called

Tags: c++, asynchronous

There is a class with 2 flag variables A and B.

These flags are changed with the methods onAChanged(bool newValue) and onBChanged(bool newValue) respectively, that are called asynchronously.

These 2 methods are both called if both flags changed or it can be that only one of the flags will change so only one of the methods is called, and the order that they are called is not guaranteed (onAChanged() can be called before or after onBChanged()).

Now, I have a method onFlagsChanged() that must be called after there is a change on any of the flags and needs to know the values of both flags so that it does different stuff based on the flags.

Note that I cannot simply call onFlagsChanged() after any of the flags is changed because after one is changed, the application might still not yet received the value for the other flag. Or it might not even receive the change for the other flag because it's not changed.

The only thing I could come up to this issue is to have a timer to wait for the next flag changed and then call the onFlagsChanged(), and if it's not received, I'd assume it's not going to be changed. However, due to the nature of the application, this is not a valid solution.

How would be your approach to this problem?

Comment: Please show some code.

Comment: There is no code because I haven't come up with any ideas on how to implement this logic.

Comment: Sounds like a job for [`std::latch`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/thread/latch). After the threads are past the point where flag changes are done, simply call `count_down` and the thread waiting for the changes simply calls `wait`...

Comment: Unfortunately the application does not support c++20 so std::latch can't be used.

Answer (score 0):

[`std::latch`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/thread/latch) seems to be exactly what you need.

If C++20 is not available, but C++11 or later is, you could use an atomic to count the threads that are done and `std::condition_variable` to send the thread waiting for the results to sleep.

**Example**

```
void ThreadFunction(std::atomic<int>& pendingTasks, std::condition_variable& cv, char const* threadName)
{
    using namespace std::chrono_literals;

    std::this_thread::sleep_for(1s); // placeholder for some work

    auto const valueBeforeDecrement = pendingTasks.fetch_sub(1, std::memory_order_release);

    std::string message = std::string(threadName) + " decremented to " + std::to_string(valueBeforeDecrement - 1) + "\n";
    std::cout << message;

    if (valueBeforeDecrement == 1)
    {
        cv.notify_one(); // inform the waiting thread all tasks are done

        message = threadName;
        message += " notified cv\n";
        std::cout << message;
    }
}

int main()
{

    std::mutex mutex;
    std::condition_variable cv;
    std::atomic<int> pendingTasks(2);

    std::thread t1(&ThreadFunction, std::ref(pendingTasks), std::ref(cv), "thread 1");
    std::thread t2(&ThreadFunction, std::ref(pendingTasks), std::ref(cv), "thread 2");

    {
        std::unique_lock lock(mutex);
        cv.wait(lock, [&pendingTasks]()
            {
                return (pendingTasks.load(std::memory_order_acquire) == 0); // prevent sporadic wakeup before tasks are actually done
            });
    }

    std::cout << "background tasks are done\n";

    t1.join();
    t2.join();
}
```

**Possible output**

```
thread 1 decremented to 0
thread 2 decremented to 1
thread 1 notified cv
background tasks are done
```

I assume there that `onAChanged` and `onBChanged` are called somewhere in the part `std::this_thread::sleep_for(1s);` is a placeholder for and none of those calls happen afterwards. If you instead want any one of the background threads to execute the `onFlagsChanged` function snchronously, you could get rid of the condition variable and simply call `onFlagsChanged` instead of `cv.notify_one()`.